# C: string literal to int array

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-literals

I have a function, taking an `int` array as argument. The `int` array is representing a string, but must be able to contain `EOF` and therefore can't be of type `char[]`. My function looks something like this:

```
_Bool fun(int str[]) {
  // does something involving checking elements for EOF, e.g.:
  return (str[0]==EOF);
}
```

For testing purposes I'd like to call `fun` with a string literal (although naturally a string literal is type `char[]` and will not be able to contain an `EOF`), in effect:

```
fun("test");
```

which will compile but with warnings about wrong argument type. That's expected since the string literal is `char[]` and the argument is `int[]`.

I could do this:

```
fun( (int*) "test");
```

which probably is equivalent, just that I'm doing the cast explicitly, same compile warnings.

I'm reading that casting `char*` to `int*` is not guaranteed to work ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291048/casting-an-int-pointer-to-a-char-ptr-and-vice-versa)). Which is natural in the general case, since if I now try to write a large `int` to `str[some_index]`, it might not fit - `str[some_index]` only has memory allocated for a `char` (tell me if I'm wrong here).

But since I won't do any such write, but rather just compare (and comparing char and int should be fine) - am I OK with either of the above? How get rid of the compile warnings in that case? Or what would be the best way to solve this?

I could of course write a simple function to copy the `char` array the string literal gives into an `int` array, value for value, but there must be a better way. Such a solution would waste memory as well.

(By the way - when testing with the `EOF`, I'll do something like this:

```
int str[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', EOF};
fun(str);
```

which should work fine.)

Comment: Why would you use EOF in the string?  That makes life inordinately hard compared with using `'\0'` to mark the end of a string.

Comment: Is this your typical string that can be null terminated or does it contain binary data?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm sending EOF to `fun` for testing purposes. `fun` otherwise operates on stdin so it does makes sense.
@Troy, don't understand your question. But since `fun` is intended to operate on data from stdin, it typically wouldn't be binary.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that suggested this technique as an implementation?

Comment: @EvilTeach: The code above is of course very reduced, but `fun()` reads from `stdin` with `getchar()`, and I want to test `fun()` through my unit testing framework. When testing, another function replaces `getchar()` that instead reads characters from an array that I can provide from my testing routines. Not only values of `char` can appear, but also `EOF` which needs an `int`. That's why I need to use an `int` array for the characters.

Comment: if fun is reading from std in, then there is no need to pass in the int array for it to process. something outside of the function should do the reading, and the fun should just process it.  that would allow you to remove the assumption that EOF is a possibility.  That would allow you to fall back to using char arrays.  If  the argument is a char array, then your unit test issue becomes trivial.

Comment: @EvilTeach: I simply need to test something reading from stdin, where EOF can appear, and I'll do that by reading from a provided array instead of stdin. Exactly how the functions are organized and what they do is another question, the code I provided is a reduction to show the principle.

Comment: @EvilTeach: In the real case, `fun` reads from stdin with getchar(), but when testing, fun instead reads from the provided int[].

No matter how I organize the functions, when testing need to provide an artificial sequence of ints provided by me, that will be read from instead reading from stdin, and I will still need to define this sequence in my testing routines. I'd like to be able to use string literals *and* EOF in this sequence for it to mimic stdin. So I still see the need of being able to combine a string literal with an EOF value and pass it to `fun`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proposed cast is a disaster, quite apart from the compiler (justifiably) complaining about it.

Assuming you're using a little-endian (Intel) machine, the function is expecting a memory layout like this (where the blank squares contain all bits zero):

```
+---+---+---+---+
| t |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
| e |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
| s |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
| t |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|EOF|EOF|EOF|EOF|
+---+---+---+---+
```

What you're passing is a memory layout like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| t | e | s | t |
+---+---+---+---+
| \0| 
+---+
```

Which is not the same thing at all.  This is completely ignoring the probable alignment problems; you're passing 5 bytes of data, without an EOF marker to mark the end of the string.

Put succinctly, *do not do it!*

Comment: That was my first question: can I do the cast this way?, and you answer it very clearly with a no and explains why, thanks.

But the more important question for me is then: how can I achieve what I want? Is writing my own function to convert the string literal (char[]) into int[] the only way?

Comment: @Carl: Yes; there is no other way to do a conversion from string literal to integer array than a D.I.Y function.  Not very hard to write, but necessary.  If you mentioned wide characters anywhere, you might be able to use wide character manipulation functions instead, but your question only asks about `int`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, sum-up:

Implied or explicit cast (`fun("test")` and `fun( (int*) "test")` repsectively) will *not* do what I want (see Jonathan Lefflers answer for details).

The way to go here is probably to write some custom function that will combine the string literal with an `EOF` value and return it all as an `int[]`.

Answer (score -2):

Try to compare with the 0, because EOF is a define of 0 and the char equivalent is '\0'

Comment: I've only ever seen EOF defined as -1.

Comment: Don't think so. EOF can't be represented as a char as far as I know. What I've read is that EOF is usually defined as -1, as Troy writes. \0 is the string termination character, and that's not the same as EOF.

Comment: EOF is *not* synonymous with 0, unless, so unless I really misread this answer, I think you're confusing EOF with NULL.

Comment: The C standard requires `EOF` to be a negative integer value (see C11 [§7.21 Input/output `<stdio.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p3)).  It is not allowed to be zero in a conforming C implementation.