# Is there a portable way to know if uintptr_t is defined in stdint.h?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdint

Preamble: I want to convert a pointer to an integer type, e.g. to check alignment. `uintptr_t` seems to be the correct type, but [it is guaranteed only in C, not in C++ (or C++11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type/1846648#1846648)

For the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifndef I_WONDER_IF_UINTPR_T_IS_DEFINED
  typedef unsigned long uintptr_t;
#endif

template <typename T>
bool isAligned(unsigned char* p) ///Checks alignment with respect to some data type
{
   return !((uintptr_t) p % sizeof(T));
}

template bool isAligned<uint16_t>(unsigned char* p);
template bool isAligned<uint32_t>(unsigned char* p);
template bool isAligned<uint64_t>(unsigned char* p);
```

2 questions:

- Is there a magic and guaranteed word that I can use where I put `I_WONDER_IF_UINTPR_T_IS_DEFINED`?
- Should I just use `unsigned long` and forget about it?

Generated assembly (when uintptr_t available): http://goo.gl/4feUNK

Note 1: I am aware than in C++11 I should use [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) in place of `sizeof` 
Note 2: I am aware of this discussion: [<cstdint> vs <stdint.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642827/cstdint-vs-stdint-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to work with an implementation not providing `uintptr_t` when including `<stdint.h>`, consider using `uintmax_t` instead, and a `static_assert` for suitability (you already established you might be on a goofy setup, so it might be too small):

```
#include <stdint.h>
static_assert(sizeof(uintmax_t) >= sizeof(void*), "need a bigger unsigned type.");

// Add code using `uintmax_t` to round-trip data-pointers here
```

There are two dis-advantages though:

1. `uintmax_t` might not be `uintptr_t`, important for overload-resolution and linking.
2. `uintmax_t` might be bigger than neccessary.

Comment: Regarding 2nd disadvantage, I am pretty sure the compiler will take care of that and remove any efficiency.

Comment: @Antonio: Depends on what all you do with it. If it can, I sure hope so. In your specific use-case, both dis-advantages should not count at all, the first due to no use, the second due to permitted optimization.

Comment: Another drawback is that with GCC, one can get a spurious warning if `uintmax_t` is used instead of `uintptr_t` ([discussion](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2018-08/msg00046.html)).

Answer (score 1):

In general, portable build systems on *nix tend to use the "autotools" approach which is to test-compile a trivial file containing the type in question, and if it compiles, you know you have that type.  If you want something simpler, you could either (a) assume `uintptr_t` is available even in C++ (probably reasonable), or (b) use `unsigned long long` and then:

```
static_assert(sizeof(unsigned long long) >= sizeof(void*), "oops");
```

Comment: You better use `unsigned long long` cause that will break on any Windows x64 system.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but, how about using `UINTPTR_MAX` for your `I_WONDER_IF_UINTPR_T_IS_DEFINED` ?