# point to low byte address of variable in c

Tags: c, pointers, bit, bitwise-and

I want to learn if this is possible:

for ex:

we have **long Lvalue = 0xFF00f41a;**

and also have **int *p;**

Can we point to last 2 byte of Lvalue

like **`p=&Lvalue <<16;`**

**p pointed frist 16 bit value** is it possible?

```
*p --> f41a;
*(p+1) --->0xFF00;
```

then if

```
p = 0xa011;
```

long Lvalue ---> 0xFF00a011

actually I need bit operations. I have 32 bit value but I can send only 16 bits and if I change 16 bit have to change first 16 bit last 16 bit of 32 bit value.

Comment: Your question is very confused. What do you want and how is that related to pointers? See [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you want to change the lower `int` part of a `long` through pointers; no, this is not possible. It breaks the strict-aliasing rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following short example will work, if `int` is aligned on 4-bytes (which seems to be guaranteed by `gcc`, see [Casting an int pointer to a char ptr and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291048)):

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                             

int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    int v = 0xcafe;                                                                                                                                                              
    int *ip = &v;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    char *cp = (char*) ip;                                                                                                                                                                                     

    printf("%hhX\n", *cp); // FE on little-endian box                                                                                                                                                                                    
    printf("%hhX\n", *(cp + 1));                                                                                                                                                                               

    *cp = 0xbe;                                                                                                                                                                                                
    *(cp + 1) = 0xba;                                                                                                                                                                                          
    printf("%X\n", *ip);                                                                                                                                                                                       

    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

You can guarantee alignment of `int` thus:

```
int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    __attribute__ ((aligned (4))) int v = 0xcafe;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Victor Sorokin

Comment: You are changing part of the integer via a char pointer. This is the bad C habit.

Comment: why it is bad @flutter

Comment: @fluter according to linked answer, this is well-known to work if int is aligned.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want 16bits of the larger 32bits type, use bit mask for the task, for example, to get the lower 16 bits of value:

```
long value = 0xFF00f41a;
long lower = value & 0xFFFF;
```

To change the lower 16 bits of value, use bit operation:

```
lower = <some thing new>;
value = (value & 0xFFFF0000) | lower;
```

Don't use pointer to access part of the 32bit value, it crates undefined bahavior when you dereference it.

Comment: yeah but I need change lower and change value of lower

Comment: @dev.burak to change the lower part again use bitwise and and or.